# Is a differentiable quantile function a sufficient condition for performing the reparametrization trick with respect to a distribution?

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, sampling, quantiles, autoencoders

The goal with the "reparametrization trick" is to to sample a noise variable $\epsilon$ from a simple distribution of our choice (like a standard Gaussian). We want to apply a deterministic transformation $T(\epsilon; a,b)$ that sends the random noise onto our intended parametrized distribution (call it $f$). With Gaussians, this is easy: to reparametrize $N(\mu, \sigma)$ we let $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ and $T(\epsilon; \mu, \sigma) = \mu + \sigma \cdot \epsilon$. But what about in general?

I was thinking that we could use the inverse sampling transform, so that for any continuous target distribution $f$ with CDF $F$, we'd have $\epsilon \sim U[0,1]$ and $T(\epsilon; \mu, \sigma) = F^{-1}(\epsilon)$. Is this accurate? Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: seems reasonable, although note that $F^{-1}$ has to be differentiable with respect to not $\epsilon$, but rather the parameters of the distribution.